# proof of $ A\otimes M\cong M $

Tags: modules, tensor-products

Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Can someone prove the $A$-module isomorphism:

$$A\otimes M \cong M?$$

(By $\otimes$ I mean tensor product.)

Comment: Surely someone can prove it. And I am pretty sure you can too... Have you tried defining maps from $A\otimes M$ to $M$ and backwards? There is essentially only one natural way to do this!

Comment: *Sigh*. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define a map $A\times M\rightarrow M$ such that $(a,m) \mapsto am$. This is clearly bilinear, so it induces a homomorphism $A\otimes M\rightarrow M$ such that $a\otimes m \mapsto am$ (by the universal property of tensor products). Surjectivity is straight forward, just take $a=1$, $m$ arbitrary. To show that the homomorphism is injective, note that any element in $A\otimes M$ can be expressed as $1\otimes m$. But this maps to $m$. If $m=0$, then $1\otimes m = 0$, hence the map is injective.

Edit: the hard part of this problem is getting a *well-defined* homomorphism. This is the appeal of the universal property. It is much easier to define (bilinear) maps on $A\times M$ than it is to define homomorphisms from the tensor product (without appealing to the universal property).

Comment: I know that this post is old, but my only question is about how to demonstrate why that function is well defined. Can you explain why it is well defined using the product $A\times M$?